# npm: how are dependencies managed?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

I installed express, mongodb, and mongoose.
This is the result of my `npm ls`:

```
/home/merc/Bookings
├─┬ connect-mongo@0.1.9 
│ └─┬ mongodb@0.9.9-8 
│   └── bson@0.0.4 
├─┬ express@3.0.0rc2 
│ ├── commander@0.6.1 
│ ├─┬ connect@2.4.2 
│ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0 
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11 
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1 
│ │ └── qs@0.4.2 
│ ├── cookie@0.0.4 
│ ├── crc@0.2.0 
│ ├── debug@0.7.0 
│ ├── fresh@0.1.0 
│ ├── methods@0.0.1 
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3 
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4 
│ └─┬ send@0.0.3 
│   └── mime@1.2.6 
├─┬ jade@0.27.2 
│ ├── commander@0.6.1 
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.0 
├─┬ mongodb@1.1.2 
│ └── bson@0.1.1 
└─┬ mongoose@3.0.0 
  ├── hooks@0.2.1 
  ├─┬ mongodb@1.1.2 
  │ └── bson@0.1.1 
  └── ms@0.1.0
```

You can clearly see that for some reason Jade is on the root directory (I assume this happened when I run "express". But then again, "mongodb" is available in different versions (0.9.9 and 1.1.2) and so is bson (0.1.1 and a worrying 0.0.4).

Hence my questions: how are dependencies managed with npm? Does every package simple install whatever they like, whichever version they pick?

I guess the question is: is this kind of duplication "normal", and "by design" so to speak?

Merc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, yes, this is by design. When you `require` a module from the `node_modules` directory, it uses the top-level directory--e.g., whichever one you specify in your `package.json`.

Other packages have their own `package.json` files, and are free to use whatever versions they want, and when they `require` them down in their own code, they will use their own `node_modules` folder.

Ideally, the modules you use have tests, etc. that ensure that versions (or even specify a range of versions, such as `0.9.x`) of dependencies they specify work well, and seeing older versions of sub-dependencies in there doesn't *necessarily* mean danger, although new versions of these modules could of course potentially fix bugs and so forth. It may be worth finding a module you're concerned about on GitHub, downloading the repository, updating the `package.json` and dependencies yourself and running the tests to see if a new version works. If so, perhaps the author would be willing to accept a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) with your update.

Comment: Thank you! Short and sweet :D